# Как загрузить изображение на сервер? PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```js
function successSave(data){
  $('#prev').css('background', 'url(' + data + ') no-repeat');
 }
function readURL(input) {
 var type   = ['image/bmp','image/gif','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png'];
 var width  = 1024;
 var height = 768;
 var size   = 524288; // bytes
 var file   = input.files[0];
 function errMsg(x) {
  alert('Error: ' + x);
  $('#prev').css('background', '#fff');
 } 
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = e.target.result;
   img.onload = function() {
    if (this.width <= width && this.height <= height) {
     var fd = new FormData;
     fd.append('img', $('.cool_inp').prop('files')[0]);
     $.ajax({
            url: 'sender.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: successSave
        });
    } else {
     errMsg('Высота или ширина изображения больше допустимого');
    }
   };
  };
 }
```

```html
<input onchange="readURL(this)" class="cool_inp" id="img" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
```

Вопрос - как сохранить полученное изображение на сервер? Искал, пробовал - не выходит

Comment: Как-то плохо искали, по запросу "php загрузка файлов" тонны информации в интернете

Comment: @andreymal да не могу ничего подходящего найти - все подключают какие-то плагины, еще что-то.. а у меня вот - передал изображение, надо сохранить... и не выходит

Comment: Первая же ссылка по этому запросу ведёт на [официальную документацию php](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php), в которой никаких плагинов нет, зато «надо сохранить» там очень даже есть

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, код пхп:

```
<?
$img = $_FILES['img'];
$name_dir = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); 
mkdir('clients/'.$name_dir);
move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'], 'clients/'.$name_dir.'/'.$img[name]);
echo 'clients/'.$name_dir.'/'.$img['name'];
?>
```